# How to share Cloudant database connection using nano in node.js application

Tags: node.js, cloudant

I am looking for guidance on how to connect to a Cloudant database once, using nano from a node.js application, such that the connection can be reused.

Right now what I am doing seems inneficient.  In app.js I require a cloudant routes file:

```
var cloudant = require('./routes/cloudant');
```

And I have various routes set up like this:

```
app.get('/person', cloudant.getperson);
```

Then in routes/cloudant.js:

```
exports.getperson = function(req, res) {
  var config = require('../config');
  var nano = require("nano")(config.cloudant_url);
  var db = nano.db.use(config.cloudant_db);

  var personid = req.params.personid;

  db.get(personid, function(err, body) {
    if(err) {
      res.send(500, err.message);
    } else {
      res.send(body);
    }
  });
}
```

So each time /person/123 is requested, I make a connection to the database but I would rather connect once and share that connection.  Is there a recommended way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

```
////////// Setup nano on app init////////////
 var config = require('../config');
  var nano = require("nano")(config.cloudant_url);
  var db = nano.db.use(config.cloudant_db);

exports.getperson = function(req, res) {
  var personid = req.params.personid;
  db.get(personid, function(err, body) { // db will be accessible here, no need to reconnect
    if(err) {
      res.send(500, err.message);
    } else {
      res.send(body);
    }
  });
}
```